# Async processing of Conduit elements

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, concurrency, conduit

Suppose we have a `conduit` stream and we'd like to process each incoming element asynchronously.

Assume

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO(..))
-- async
import Control.Concurrent.Async (Concurrently(..), Async, wait, withAsync, mapConcurrently)
-- conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit as C (ConduitT, runConduit)
import Data.Conduit ((.|))
import qualified Data.Conduit.Combinators as C (sinkLazy, map, mapM)
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as C (sourceList)
```

This first implementation `notConcurrently` doesn't do the job since `wait` blocks the execution of the conduit at each element.

```
notConcurrently :: MonadIO m => (a -> IO b) -> C.ConduitT a b m ()
notConcurrently io = C.mapM (\x -> liftIO $ withAsync (io x) wait)
```

Another possibility is to pass the `Async` down the conduit and then `wait` at the end:

```
concurrentlyC2 :: MonadIO m => (t -> IO a) -> C.ConduitT t (Async a) m ()
concurrentlyC2 io = C.mapM $ \x -> liftIO $ withAsync (io x) pure

awaitSink :: (MonadIO m) => C.ConduitT (Async a) o m [a]
awaitSink = do
  xs <- C.sinkList
  liftIO $ traverse wait xs
```

The problem here is that we need to tell the main thread to wait for all the child asyncs otherwise they are `cancel`ed. Any suggestions?

---

some test code :

```
blip :: MonadIO m => Int -> m ()
blip i = liftIO $ do
  _ <- threadDelay 1000000
  putStrLn $ unwords ["hello from thread", show i]


test1 :: IO [()]
test1 = C.runConduit $ C.sourceList [1..10] .| concurrentlyC2 blip .| awaitSink
```

Comment: Presumably you want some back pressure so you don't have unlimited `Async`s at once. That suggests you keep around a queue of active `Async`s, and wait for one (if necessary) before adding another.

Comment: @dfeuer I found this `asyncMapC` that more or less does what you describe https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-algorithms-0.0.11.0/src/Data/Conduit/Algorithms/Async.hs . Thank you!

Comment: You may also want to look at `streamly`, which has several concurrency strategies.